# Shopify send product with options on shopify

Tags: php, insert, shopify

```
$productShopify = array(
    "body_html" => $product->description[(int)$id_lang],
    "created_at" => $date_now,
    "handle" => $product->name[(int)$id_lang],
    "id" => $product->id,
        "images"=>array(array("src"=>$ProducDATA['image']),
        //  array("src"=>$imageShopify[0]),
            array("src"=>$imageShopify[1])
        ),
    "options" => array("name" => $group_name[0],array("name" => $group_name[1])),
    "product_type" => $ProducDATA['Category_1'],
    "published_at" => $date_now,
    "published_scope" => "global",
    "tags" => $Tag,
    "template_suffix" => null,
    "title" => $product->name[(int)$id_lang],
    "variants" => array(
        array(
            "barcode" => $product->ean13,
            "grams" => $product->weight,
            "option1" => $attribute_name[0][1],
            "price" => $product->price,
            "sku" => $ProducDATA['manufacturer_reference'].'-1',
            "title" => $product->name[(int)$id_lang],
           // "id" => 808950810,
            "product_id" => $product->id,
            "inventory_quantity" => $product->id
        ),
        array(
            "barcode" => $product->ean13,
            "grams" => $product->weight,
            "option2" => $attribute_name[0][2],
            "price" => $product->price,
            "sku" => $ProducDATA['manufacturer_reference'].'-2',
            "title" => $product->name[(int)$id_lang],
           // "id" => 808950810,
            "product_id" => $product->id,
            "inventory_quantity" => $product->id
        ),
        array(
            "barcode" => $product->ean13,
            "grams" => $product->weight,
            "option1" => $attribute_name[1][1],
            "price" => $product->price,
            "sku" => $ProducDATA['manufacturer_reference'].'-3',
            "title" => $product->name[(int)$id_lang],
           // "id" => 808950810,
            "product_id" => $product->id,
            "inventory_quantity" => $product->id
        ),
        array(
            "barcode" => $product->ean13,
            "grams" => $product->weight,
            "option2" => $attribute_name[1][2],
            "price" => $product->price,
            "sku" => $ProducDATA['manufacturer_reference'].'-4',
            "title" => $product->name[(int)$id_lang],
           // "id" => 808950810,
            "product_id" => $product->id,
            "inventory_quantity" => $product->id
        )
    ),
    "vendor" => $ProducDATA['marque'],
);
```

I can not find the solution to send a product with several options on shopify, syntax error

I try everything but impossible to understand the principle if you have an idea
I can send the product on shopify with 1 option but not +

I can send the product on shopify with only 1 option but I do not start with Php be indulgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your 4 variants should have a value for *both* option1 and an option2. For example:

```
       array(
            "barcode" => $product->ean13,
            "grams" => $product->weight,
            "option1" => $attribute_name[0][1],
            "option2" => $attribute_name[0][2],
            "price" => $product->price,
            "sku" => $ProducDATA['manufacturer_reference'].'-1',
            "title" => $product->name[(int)$id_lang],
           // "id" => 808950810,
            "product_id" => $product->id,
            "inventory_quantity" => $product->id
        )
```

Also, you should check the response code and response body from the Shopify API. If your request fails, it will contain information that is useful in tracking down the error.